# Need help in adding new lookup column in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-server, lookup-column

I have a list for Person in which there is a lookup column for StateID of States list. In States list there is a lookup column for CountryID of Countries. I want to add CountryID to Person list by using existing StateID lookup column, but when I edit StateID column from List settings of Persons list I didn't see choice for selecting CountryID lookup column to add in Persons list. 
Please help, please let know if this is the correct way to do this or if it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

States list must be have CountryID, then you can add that to Persons list.
you can add CountryID as calculated id to States list and then you can see that when you want to create StateID lookup column.

Comment: When I am trying to add new Calculated column, I didn't see StateID in available columns list, maybe I didn't get what you meant to say

Comment: when you want to add CountryID lookup column to the States List CountryID under "Add a column to show each of these additional fields:" you cant choose ID and you have column with tile Country:ID and name Country_x003a_ID

Comment: Thanks for reply, I added new column to States list for Country:ID as suggested by you, but it still doesn't appear in Persons StateID Lookup column for adding other columns from States list